# Borrow of moved value: `stdout`

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I created a `stdout` field in my struct `TermWriter`, because I want to be able to use an external stdout (e.g. from the [Termion](https://github.com/redox-os/termion) crate) and also a mock stdout for tests (also a external `cursor_pos()` method and a mocked one for tests).

```
pub struct TermWriter<W: Write> {
    pub input: String,
    cursor_pos: Position,
    stdout: W,
}

impl<W: Write> TermWriter<W> {
    pub fn new(input: String, stdout: W) -> Self {
        Self {
            input,
            cursor_pos: Position { x: 1, y: 2 },
            stdout,
        }
    }

    pub fn right(&mut self) -> Result<(), InputError> {
        if self.cursor_pos.x <= self.input.len() as u16 {
            write!(self.stdout, "{}", termion::cursor::Right(1))?;

            let cursor_pos = self.stdout.cursor_pos()?;

            self.cursor_pos.x = cursor_pos.0;
        }

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

So TermWriter's `new()` method accepts a stdout as a parameter. However, there's a problem here:

```
pub fn get_input(
    input_keys: impl Iterator<Item = Result<Key, std::io::Error>>,
    stdout: &mut impl Write,
) -> Result<Input, InputError> {
    let input = String::new();
    let mut term_writer = TermWriter::new(input, stdout);

    for key in input_keys {
        match key.unwrap() {
            Key::Right => term_writer.right()?,
            _ => {}
        }

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }

    let input = term_writer.input.trim().to_owned();

    Ok(Input::Text(input))
}
```

`stdout` was moved here: `TermWriter::new(input, stdout)`, so `stdout.flush().unwrap();` is borrowing a moved value.

How to prevent this moved value/borrowing problem?

Comment: Try `TermWriter::new(input, &mut *stdout);`

Comment: @PitaJ Thanks for the suggestion, but I get `cannot borrow \`stdout\` as mutable more than once at a time`.

Comment: `term_writer.stdout.flush().unwrap()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stdout` is accessible from your newly created `term_writer`, so this should work (the same thing you do for `input`):

```rs
term_writer.stdout.flush().unwrap()
```

Another thing is that you should take `Write` instead of `&mut Write`, since [any `&mut Write` also implements `Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-for-%26mut%20W).

```rs
pub fn get_input(
    ...
    stdout: impl Write,
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple solution. One question: So here I'm doing `term_writer.stdout.flush().unwrap()` but everywhere else I'm doing `stdout.flush()`. Does this mean I have a design issue here?

Comment: @alexchenco are you referring to the lack of `term_writer` or the lack of `unwrap`?

Comment: I'm referring to the lack of `term_writer`.

Comment: @alexchenco As long as you're not creating multiple `stdout`, only one of those should compile. So just use whichever works.